# Website invalid security certificate

Tags: tls

On a home LAN I encountered this error both in Linux Firefox (an ubuntu vmware VM on Win7) and from my Android phone browser from a shopping website during the checkout process a few days ago. Could this indicate some sort of MITM compromise (eg in the LAN router)?  DNS compromise? Could this also be from one of the content delivery network (CDN) machines serving the paypal content being incorrectly configured or being compromised?

> This Connection is Untrusted
>
> You have asked Firefox to connect securely to www.paypal.com, but we
>   can't confirm that your connection is secure.
>   Normally, when you try to connect securely, sites will present trusted
>   identification to prove that you are going to the right place.
>   However, this site's identity can't be verified.
>
> What Should I Do?
>   If you usually connect to this site without problems, this error could
>   mean that someone is trying to impersonate the site, and you shouldn't
>   continue.
>   This site uses HTTP Strict Transport Security (HSTS) to specify that
>   Firefox only connect to it securely. As a result, it is not possible
>   to add an exception for this certificate.
>
> www.paypal.com uses an invalid security certificate.
>
> The certificate is only valid for the following names:
>   google.com, *.2mdn.net, *.android.com, *.appengine.google.com (many
>   more names...)

Running nslookup on the linux machine

@1pm

> nslookup www.paypal.com
>   Server:                 127.0.1.1
>   Address:                127.0.1.1#53
>
> Non-authoritative answer:
>   Name:             www.paypal.com
>   Address: 216.58.217.194

Then @1:45

> nslookup www.paypal.com
>   Server:                 127.0.1.1
>   Address:                127.0.1.1#53
>
> Non-authoritative answer:
>   www.paypal.com    canonical name = www.paypal.com.akadns.net.
>   www.paypal.com.akadns.net   canonical name =
>   ppdirect.paypal.com.akadns.net.
>   ppdirect.paypal.com.akadns.net        canonical name =
>   wlb.paypal.com.akadns.net.
>   wlb.paypal.com.akadns.net             canonical name =
>   www.paypal.com.edgekey.net.
>   www.paypal.com.edgekey.net            canonical name =
>   e3694.a.akamaiedge.net.
>   Name:                                 e3694.a.akamaiedge.net
>   Address: 184.86.122.156

What would be a remediation plan? Replace the home LAN router? Would all the devices on the home LAN also be suspect?

Comment: Can you share the URL of the site?

Comment: Can you please post the issuer of the SSL certificate? Many AV programs install their own SSL certificate as a CA root certificate (and therefore acting as a MITM), in order to be able to inspect all HTTPS traffic. However, what puzzles me is that you have this issue in multiple devices (and one of them is a Linux laptop with presumably no AV installed) so the MITM must take place in your router.

Comment: Actually, it would be interesting to see the whole certificate here: the list of domain this cert is valid for is weird

Comment: The invalid certificate error above was for https://www.paypal.com which my browser was redirected to for payment/checkout from drugstore.com (I did not make the payment).

Comment: @Stephane: More names in the 'The certificate is only valid for the following names:'  list                                                                          *.au.doubleclick.net, *.cc-dt.com, *.cloud.google.com, *.de.doubleclick.net, *.doubleclick.com, *.doubleclick.net, *.fls.doubleclick.net, *.fr.doubleclick.net, *.google-analytics.com, *.google.ac, *.google.ad, *.google.ae, *.google.af, *.google.ag, *.google.al, ... oogle.ws, googlecommerce.com, gstatic.com, urchin.com, youtu.be, youtube.com, youtubeeducation.com

Comment: @dr01 The Issuer appeared to be: CN: Google Internet Authority G2 O: Google Inc, Issued on 9/29/2015

Comment: As @stephane asked, can you please post the whole certificate here?

Comment: This looks like a CDN flunk, really. Akamai has similar issue a few times already: they redirected traffic to the wrong accelerator and, as a result, broke TLS for many web site. Since this is a local issue (it happens only near the incorrectly configured CDN endpoint), it's hard to detect. Unfortunately, to be sure of that, we need to have a copy of that certificate (the whole X509 cert, not a cut and paste of some properties).

Comment: @Stephane Firefox didn't seem to give me the option to view the certificate with the error, so I didn't save it at the time (and now a few days later https://www.paypal.com seemingly loads ok). When I saw this issue I only got a screenshot of the certificate viewer dialog on my android phone (which only displayed the certificate properties, serial number, issuer, SHA-25 fingerprint... ). I'd like this to be a CDN flunk, but it sounds like I'd need the X509 cert to confirm? Would that offending X509 be cached anywhere (currently paypal.com loads w/out error) ?

Answer (score 3):

This is a really bad one. Someone delivered this fake certificate to you in the intend of being able to decrypting your HTTPS connection. As it's paypal.com it's very likely that the attacker wants to capture your credentials. This can result in looting your bank account so you better don't trust this connection.

Its hard to say in which step of the connection the MITM attack was performed or if it anyway was a MITM. It could also be maleware that installed a proxy on your host that replaces the real certificates with faked ones.

MITM Attacks can be performed in the LAN easily but can also be based on the manipulation of your or your ISPs router.